# Querying a specific record in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm used to working with relational databases, where you could target a specific record. For instance, using the pseudo sql below.

```
SELECT id, name, otherVar FROM students WHERE id=:studentId
```

However, I am unsure how to even approach this in Lotus Notes with its flat data model. I have been googling but keep coming up with hits on how to update Lotus Notes itself, not a document inside of Lotus Notes. If someone with the some LN expertise could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the SQL statement as analogy, lets say you have a view `students` with columns `id`, `name` and `otherVar`. The column `id` should be sorted (either in ascending or descending). So the view looks something like this

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ id ║ name       ║ otherVar    ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Daniel     ║ ----------  ║
║ 2  ║ Joseph     ║ ----------  ║
║ 3  ║ Michelle   ║ ----------  ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

To lookup this view you would write something like this in LotusScript:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession 'Get current session
Dim currentDB As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim studentId As String

studentId = "<STUDENT_ID>" 'The student ID that needs to be searched
Set currentDB = session.CurrentDatabase 'Get current database
Set view = currentDB.GetView("students") 'Get the view
Set doc = view.GetDocumentByKey(studentId, True) 'Look up the view with student ID to get the student document
```

Do a simple Google search for `NotesView` for more information. In formula language you can write it as:

```
@DbLookup("Notes":"NoCache"; ""; "students"; "<STUDENT_ID>"; "<FIELD TO BE RETRIEVED>"; [FailSilent]);
```

But formula is less flexible that LotusScript if you want to do complex calculations.

Comment: I'm marking yours as the answer but I also found a function on the Database class called getDocumentByID. I didn't find it before because I was under the mistaken impression that a function like that would have been on the View class. I guess it makes sense though since a View is just a way of organizing what's in a database.

Comment: @JRSmith: `getDocumentByID` function gets the document by Notes ID. There is another thing in Lotus Notes called Universal ID and the concept itself is a separate topic so I will not be digressing here. `getDocumentByID` function will fetch the document based on Notes ID which is generated by Lotus Notes when a document is created. Are you sure that `studentId` is same as document's Notes ID? If yes then it work, if no then you would have to go via `NotesView`.

Comment: It's better to refer to it as the NoteID, not the Notes ID -- as the latter is easily confused with the Notes ID file, which is also an entirely different concept.  The NoteID is not a stable value.  You can never be sure that it matches anything.  It's not even guaranteed to match for the same document in two different replicas of the same database.

Comment: Also, it's important to point out that GetDocumentByKey only works in this case if studentId matches the value of the first sorted column in the "students" view. Failing to set the sort property on the column is a common cause of confusion.

Comment: @JRSmith The reason that getDocumentByID is not a method of a NotesView is that the view doesn't organize data by ID. As Richard has noted, GetDocumentByKey can be used to select an individual document by the value of the first sorted column, or if you use an array as the key for GetDocumentByKey, by multiple sorted columns (in order, of course).

Comment: @All the above comments have been helpful in getting my head around this, i'm glad most of our clients don't use LN, upvotes for all!

Comment: @JRSmith: Notes is very powerful, if you just know the platform it is not complicated at all. I could say I am glad I am not using SQL for my solutions. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try working with Domino Data Services too. Have your Notes administrator open up the database for REST Services work and you can get Domino data almost from anywhere! See [Domino Data Services manual on the web](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html#ddapi_ref)